# psidR: build.panel() returns duplicate Error

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, na

Just tried to run the build.panel function within the psidR package. It did download all the rda files successfully for the first part of the script and I put them into a separate folder. However, now that I run the function I get an error code :

`Error in [.data.table(yind, , :=((as.character(ind.nas)), NA)) :
Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected).
In addition: Warning message:
In [.data.table(tmp, , :=((nanames), NA_real_), with = FALSE) :
with=FALSE ignored, it isn't needed when using :=. See ?':=' for examples.`

Might be my fault of ill-defining my variables? I just use the getNamesPSID function and plug it into a data.table, similar to the example code:

```
library(psidR)
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)
cwf <- read.xlsx("http://psidonline.isr.umich.edu/help/xyr/psid.xlsx")

id.ind.educ1 <- getNamesPSID("ER30010", cwf)
id.fam.income1 <- getNamesPSID("V81", cwf)

famvars1 <- data.table(year=c(1968, 1969, 1970),
                       income1=id.fam.income1
                       )

indvars1 <- data.table(year=c(1968, 1969, 1970),
                       educ1=id.ind.educ1
                       )

build.panel(datadir = "/Users/Adrian/Documents/ECON 490/Heteroskedastic Dependency/Dependency/RDA", fam.vars = famvars1, ind.vars = indvars1, sample = "SRC", design = 3)
```

If you omit the datadir argument, R will download the corresponding datasets to a temporary directory. It will be printed in the output where exactly. As long as the R process runs you should have access to it and can copy it elsewhere. Error should be reproducible. Might take a bit until it downloads the datasets the first time.

If it relates to the NA's within each getNames argument, is there a workaround where I still preserve the corresponding year so I can tell that apart in my panel?

I know there was a similar issue on the corresponding github page relating to zips with the same name as one of the data sets. However, my folder only contains the correct datasets and no zips.

I also tried to exclude the NA cases but that messed up the length of my vectors. I also tried it with a standard data.frame.

I also checked my resulting famvars / indvars dataframes for duplicates with Excel but there are none besides the NA's, which, according to the github example found on https://github.com/floswald/psidR should be included in the dataset...

Thanks so much for your help :)

EDIT: here the traceback():

```
3: [.data.table(yind, , :=((as.character(ind.nas)), NA))
2: yind[, :=((as.character(ind.nas)), NA)]
1: build.panel(datadir = "/Users/Adrian/Documents/ECON 490/Heteroskedastic Dependency/Dependency/RDA",
fam.vars = famvars, ind.vars = indvars, sample = "SRC", design = 3)
```

EDIT'': thank you @Axeman, I cut down the reproducible example. My actual data.table contains many more variables.

UPDATE: 
Just for anyone running into a similar issue:
After trying to find a way to get the function to work I decided to instead manually merge all the files and dataframes. Be prepared, its a mammoth project but so is any analysis of the PSID. I followed the instructions found here: http://asdfree.com/panel-study-of-income-dynamics-psid.html and combined them with helper function of the psidR package (getNamesPSID mainly, to get the variable names in each wave). So far, very successful. Only wish that there were more articles on the exact functioning of the survey package on the web.

Comment: You are unlikely to receive a useful answer without making a much smaller reproducible example.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there's no duplicated name columns in the call that throws the error?

Comment: Yes I used the duplicate values/unique values function in Excel and the only ones coming up are the NA's...

Comment: You might try and raise this with the `psidR` maintainer: https://github.com/floswald/psidR please also report the versions of each package as it's possible the versions are incompatible

Comment: Thanks, yes I filed an issue thread on the github as well. I've also seen that there were some other issues in the past with some NA strings so might simply be an internal problem of the package...